# Find amount by group

Tags: python, pyspark

Please help me understand PySpark

I have a dataframe, how can I find the sum of each parameter by PySpark?

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|o_id|col_1|col_3|col_9|ser_1|ser_2|ser_9|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   0|  103|   17|   73|   c1|   c2|   c2|
|   1|  323|  245|   66|   c2|   c1|   c3|
|   2|  112|   96| 1452|   c3|   c2|   c1|
|   3|   46|  746|    4|   c3|   c2|   c3|
|   4|   82|  379|   78|   c1|   c1|   c2|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

How to find the sum of all occurrences of c1 and so on.

How would you get a pivot table of this type?

```
+----+-----+
| ser|  sum|
+----+-----+
|  c1| 2261| 
|  c2| 1333| 
|  c3|  228| 
+----+-----+
```

If there were fewer columns, then I would easily do the `.groupby()`, but there are a lot of columns (a lot more), and I don’t understand how you can group everything without using python loops, which will significantly reduce the speed of the code.

```
df_1 = (df.groupby('ser_1').sum('col_1'))
...
df_x = (df.groupby('ser_x').sum('col_x'))
```

Are there more elegant solutions?

Comment: Can you explain how do you get the `sum` as `2261` for `c1`?

Comment: ser_1 - type of service on the first day
col_1 - the cost of the service on the first day
accordingly, the cost of all services ser_1 will be equal to `col_1 [0] + col_1 [4] + col_3 [1] + col_3 [4] + col_9 [2]`
And I don't want to manually create a separate dataframe for each pair of columns
`df_1 = (df.groupby ('ser_1'). sum ('col_1'))
...`
Perhaps there is a nicer way to do it. Like
`df_1 = (df.groupby (col (col ("ser_1) + col (" ser_2 "))). sum ((col (col (" col_1) + col ("col_2"))))`
But there are a lot of columns, and I don't think this is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computation can be optimized using the following strategy.

1. Create a mapping between `ser_*` and `col_*` columns to create an array of structs.
2. Explode the array of structs into rows.
3. Group by the `key` and sum on the `value` of the exploded rows.

### Working Example

#### Data Setup

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [(0, 103, 17, 73, "c1", "c2", "c2",),
        (1, 323, 245, 66, "c2", "c1", "c3",),
        (2, 112, 96, 1452, "c3", "c2", "c1",),
        (3, 46, 746, 4, "c3", "c2", "c3",),
        (4, 82, 379, 78, "c1", "c1", "c2",), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("o_id", "col_1", "col_3", "col_9", "ser_1", "ser_2", "ser_9",))
```

#### Create Mapping Between `ser_*` and `col_*` columns

> The mapping is hard-coded here as there is no one-to-one mapping between`col` and `ser` based on their index since `col_3` maps to `ser_2` from question. If there exists a one-to-one mapping the combinations can be generated via code.

```py
ser_arrays = F.array(F.col("ser_1"), F.col("ser_2"), F.col("ser_9")).alias("ser")
col_arrays = F.array(F.col("col_1"), F.col("col_3"), F.col("col_9")).alias("col_val")

df_col_ser_map = df.select(F.arrays_zip(ser_arrays, col_arrays).alias("mapped_col_ser"))

df_col_ser_map.show(truncate=False)

#+---------------------------------+
#|mapped_col_ser                   |
#+---------------------------------+
#|[{c1, 103}, {c2, 17}, {c2, 73}]  |
#|[{c2, 323}, {c1, 245}, {c3, 66}] |
#|[{c3, 112}, {c2, 96}, {c1, 1452}]|
#|[{c3, 46}, {c2, 746}, {c3, 4}]   |
#|[{c1, 82}, {c1, 379}, {c2, 78}]  |
#+---------------------------------+
```

#### Explode Mapped Column

```py
df_col_ser_exploded = df_col_ser_map.select(F.explode("mapped_col_ser").alias("exploded_col_ser"))

df_col_ser_exploded.show()

#+----------------+
# |exploded_col_ser|
# +----------------+
# |       {c1, 103}|
# |        {c2, 17}|
# |        {c2, 73}|
# |       {c2, 323}|
# |       {c1, 245}|
# |        {c3, 66}|
# |       {c3, 112}|
# |        {c2, 96}|
# |      {c1, 1452}|
# |        {c3, 46}|
# |       {c2, 746}|
# |         {c3, 4}|
# |        {c1, 82}|
# |       {c1, 379}|
# |        {c2, 78}|
# +----------------+
```

#### Group on key and Aggregate Value

```py
df_col_ser_exploded.groupBy((df_col_ser_exploded["exploded_col_ser"]["ser"]).alias("ser")) \
    .agg(F.sum(df_col_ser_exploded["exploded_col_ser"]["col_val"]).alias("sum")).show()


# +---+----+
# |ser| sum|
# +---+----+
# | c1|2261|
# | c3| 228|
# | c2|1333|
# +---+----+
```

Comment: Thanks! Great solution!
But I can't get away from manually entering all the columns? There are a lot of them.
ser_arrays = F.array (F.col ("ser_1"), F.col ("ser_2"), F.col ("ser_9")). alias ("ser")
And that means I need to first enter the entire range manually ... (

Comment: @Dima from your question, `col_3` is mapped to `ser_2`, is this correct? If `ser_2` is mapped to `col_2` then the array can be generated.

Comment: Yes that's right. I mean if I need mapped more than 100 columns, is it all done manually? When I try to do it through a loop in python, the spark generates a huge number of jobs.

Comment: If the mapping between `ser` and `col` is not derivable from a loop, then the mapping has to be hard coded. However, with the solution I have posted won't created a lot of jobs, since the aggregations are computed after the transformation.